# Incorrect number of Contours on javacv?

Tags: java, opencv

I have write simple code to retrieve number of Contours in a image and get the number of Contours in the image. But it always gives incorrect answer. Please can some one explain about this ?

```
 import com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader;
 import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
 import static com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.*;
 import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
 import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
 import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;
 import java.io.File;
 import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

 public class TestBeam {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         CvMemStorage storage=CvMemStorage.create();
         CvSeq squares = new CvContour();
         squares = cvCreateSeq(0, sizeof(CvContour.class), sizeof(CvSeq.class), storage);
         JFileChooser f=new JFileChooser();
         int result=f.showOpenDialog(f);//show dialog box to choose files
             File myfile=null;
             String path="";
         if(result==0){
             myfile=f.getSelectedFile();//selected file taken to myfile
             path=myfile.getAbsolutePath();//get the path of the file
         }
         IplImage src = cvLoadImage(path);//hear path is actual path to image
         IplImage grayImage    = IplImage.create(src.width(), src.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
         cvCvtColor(src, grayImage, CV_RGB2GRAY);
         cvThreshold(grayImage, grayImage, 127, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
         CvSeq cvSeq=new CvSeq();
         CvMemStorage memory=CvMemStorage.create();
         cvFindContours(grayImage, memory, cvSeq, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class), CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
         System.out.println(cvSeq.elem_size());
         CanvasFrame cnvs=new CanvasFrame("Beam");
         cnvs.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         cnvs.showImage(src);
         //cvShowImage("Final ", src);
         
     }
 }
```

This is the sample image that I used

[image]

But Code always returns output as 8. Please can someone explain this?

Comment: I get 19 in this image, using Python API.

Comment: @AbidRahmank Do you have any idea about its meaning ?

Comment: I got 19 because, one full image boundary, then 9 outer boundaries and 9 inner boundaries of 9 squares. If you had inverted the image, you would get 18 i think, because image boundary will be gone. visit : http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/06/hi-this-article-is-tutorial-which-try.html

Answer (score 1):

`cvSeq.elem_size()` will return size of sequence element in bytes and not the number of contours. That is why output is 8 every time.
Please refer following link for more information.
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/dynamic_structures.html#cvseq

For finding number of contours you can use following snippet

```
int i = 0;
while(cvSeq != null){
i = i + 1;
cvSeq = cvSeq.h_next();
}
System.out.println(i);
```

With the parameters you have provided CV_RETR_EXTERNAL will only provide external contour that is image boundary in your image(provided you are not inverting the image). You can use CV_RETR_LIST to get all the contours. Visit following link for more information on the parameters.
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours